# How to set NuGet restore in TFS to take the highest version available?

Tags: tfs, package, nuget, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore

Let's say my solution have 2 package dependencies:

3rdParty.CompanyA.ProductA version 4.0.1
and 3rdParty.CompanyB.ProductB version 2.0.1

Both packages reference other package dependency **"C"**.
The dependency for the first one is set to "higher then 1.2 - (>1.2)" , and the other one set to "higher then 1.8 - (>1.8)".

[image]

When I'm **locally compiling** the solution all works fine and the "C" version in the bin directory is the **newest "1.8" as expected....**
But when I compile this solution in **TFS** and reference the same **.Nuget\NuGet.config** file I'm getting the **old 1.2v "C"** version in the bin directory and therefore my product getting broken.
Is there a special configuration to notify TFS restore to take the version that will match all dependencies?

## Update

I think I know where my issue is coming from and yet I'm net quite understand it.
In TFS I'm compiling and restoring packages for 8 projects.
After the compilation is over I run **UnitTest with the "Test Assemblies" step.**
I found out that with the default setting my unittest get broken due it referencing old DLL. But when I turn on the **"Run In Parallel" it's working as expected.**

Comment: What happens when you remove your local `packages` folder and let the package restore run again?

Comment: Both 1.2 and 1.8 folders are created in the package folder. But only the newer 1.8 get copied to bin as expected

Comment: What's the result if you disable your test related task first? Just leave the build task. Could you got the right version? My point is trying to narrow down if it's related to the test task  mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if totally got your point. In my opinion, the two packages should in the some project. If not, there will be two bin folders one for 1.2 and one for 1.8.

It's a cousin dependencies concept in Nuget Restore:

> When different package versions are referred to at the same distance
>   in the graph from the application, NuGet **uses the lowest version
>   that satisfies all version requirements** (as with the lowest
>   applicable version and floating versions rules). In the image below,
>   for example, version 2.0 of Package B will satisfy the other >=1.0
>   constraint, and will thus be used:
>
> ***Source: [How NuGet resolves package dependencies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/dependency-resolution#dependency-resolution-in-nuget-3x)***

[image]

It's also using NuGet.exe int TFS NuGet restore task. There shouldn't be any additional settings or parameters. Suggest you to enable debug model in TFS and go through more detail logs for trouble shooting. Otherwise, just use the simply workaround change the dependency for the first one also setting to "higher then 1.8 - (>1.8)"

---

Update

Suggest you just turn on the "Run In Parallel"  of the VS test task, tests will run in parallel leveraging available cores of the machine. For how tests are run in parallel please refer [Parallel Test Execution](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/10/10/parallel-test-execution/) A good choice in this situation.

Comment: I think I know where my issue is coming from and yet I'm net quite understand it.
In TFS I'm compiling and restoring packages for 8 projects.
After the compilation is over I run UnitTest with the "Test Assemblies" step.
I found out that with the default setting my unittest get broken due it referencing old DLL. But when I turn on the "Run In Parallel" it's working as expected.

Comment: @AviramFireberger There must also be both 1.2 and 1.8 folders  created in the package folder on TFS build.  Not sure why the normal test step will copy the old 1.2v in this situation.  Suggest you just turn on the "Run In Parallel"  of the VS test task, tests will run in parallel leveraging available cores of the machine. For how tests are run in parallel please refer [Parallel Test Execution](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/10/10/parallel-test-execution/) A good choice either for the issue or reducing the time of test step.

Comment: Yep, That's what I did, as I mentioned in the question. But I want to know why it's acting like that, Why in parallel it's working as expected, and if it not set, it would take the old version?